# How to check the status of a service running on a linux machine using JAVA

Tags: java, linux, unix

I want to develop a web application(Java) which checks the statuses of services of all our applications.

Can some one help me on how to write a java code to do so for a service running on a linux machine(like a tomcat service)

I have 4 linux servers which has services running on all servers.So,I would like to connect them from java itself and get the process status.

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: No idea of where to start as I am not aware of how to read a linux process  in java.So,Going through google links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        JSch objJSch = new JSch();
        Session objSession = objJSch.getSession("userName", "ip_address");
        objSession.setPassword("password");
        objSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        objSession.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
        Channel objChannel = objSession.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) objChannel).setCommand("ps aux");
        InputStream in = objChannel.getInputStream();
        objChannel.connect();
        String s;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("disconnecting...");
        objChannel.disconnect();
        objSession.disconnect();
        System.out.println("disconnected.");
}
```

The JSch library enables ssh connection. You can go through other examples in the following [link](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) Add the following dependency else download and place the jar in your path:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
</dependency>
```

You can repeat the process for 'n' number of servers inside a loop. The above code would print the following output: (dependent on the os. i am using ubuntu, forgive me because of the weird table design, couldn't format it properly).

||USER||PID||%CPU||%MEM||VSZ||RSS||TTY||STAT||START||TIME||COMMAND||

||root||2202||0.0||0.0||144768||6860||?||S||04:57||0:00||tint2||

....//next row

....//next row

The STAT column denotes the status of the application. The following are the plausible states of a application:

D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)

R    running or runnable (on run queue)

S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)

T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced

W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)

X    dead (should never be seen)

Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

(above information taken from [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473880/how-to-check-the-process-is-already-running-or-not))

Comment: This is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose can you please clarify? it would help me improve my answer.

Comment: I would like to connect to remote linux server and get the process status using java.
As I have multiple linux machines

Comment: @Abhishek
Can you elaborate the answer in a way that I can call it remotely from my windows machine by calling IP and providing authentication

Comment: @saivinod i have modified my answer please go through it and give your comments

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose i have modified my answer. kindly go through and add your comments

Comment: @saivinod if this answers your question please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Abhishek Thaks for your answer.I got it almost,except that I want the status of a specific service.When I try service XXX status ,It throws an error.Could you let me know how to fetch the service status

Comment: @saivinod could you please be more specific?

Comment: @saivinod if the above has answered your question please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @abhishek, to be more specific, I want the status of a service named hipchat.What should be my command instead of ps aux ?

Comment: @saivinod "ps aux | grep hipchat" this would return only the line of hipchat if it is running...

Comment: @saivinod did my solution solve your issue? if yes then don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.